# Theewaterskloof Dam Bathymetry

Tags: geospatial, africa

I am trying to find bathymetry for [Theewaterskloof Dam](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Theewaterskloof+Dam,+South+Africa/@-34.0780515,19.2869783,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x1dcdec735f9bc571:0x303d47b057bd0b08!8m2!3d-34.078056!4d19.289167), South Africa, in GIS format. Almost any resolution will do. Bathymetry latest before 2000 at least or the latest one is also good. Where can I start searching? I have tried a few sites and links. No luck though!!

Comment: Have you been able to find bathymetric data from South Africa for Inland lakes/dams??
I have done a pretty deep search, but I couldn't find much data.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Inland bathymetry data for South Africa is not easy to locate. I found some sources that seem promising. I don't have time right now to fully dig through each of these sources to see if they have exactly the right thing, so here's a link dump of all the relevant-sounding data sources I found. If you do find exactly what you want at one of these links, please help others by sharing a direct link (post a new answer, edit this answer, or post it as a comment).

Some sources of geospatial data for Africa:

- River Discharge Data, no bathymetry data: https://daac.ornl.gov/cgi-bin/dataset_lister.pl?p=18#hydrology_anchor
- https://earlywarning.usgs.gov/fews/search/Africa/Southern%20Africa
- http://geoportal.rcmrd.org/layers/?limit=100&offset=0
- https://africaopendata.org/dataset?tags=gis

Here are a couple sources of bathymetry data that don't appear to include what you're looking for, but it might be worth taking a closer look at them to see if I missed something.

- The [International Hydrographic Organization Data Centre for Digital Bathymetry](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/iho/) defines bathymetry as *oceanic* depth soundings. They don't appear to have coverage of non-oceanic water bodies.
- The [ETOPO1 Global Relief Model](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/global.html) also appears to be limited to oceanic bathymetry.

[NASA's EarthData](https://search.earthdata.nasa.gov/search?m=-35.0419921875!19.107421875!5!1!0!0%2C2&ac=true&fdc=Land%20Process%20Distributed%20Active%20Archive%20Center%20(LPDAAC)) is an interactive data download tool that provides access to an extremely long list of earth surface raster data. Have a look at the topography and elevation raster products to see if they include bathymetry.

Searching for "africa gis data hydro" yielded multiple sources of *hydrography* and *hydrology* data ([for example](http://www.fao.org/geonetwork/srv/en/main.search?any=awrd&themekey=%22watersheds%22)), which includes stream lines and watershed boundaries. That's not really what you want, but sometimes bathymetry data is included on pages that include hydro data (perhaps not correctly labeled with the term bathymetry).

Comment: I already tried the International Hydrographic Organization Data Centre for Digital Bathymetry, Earthdata and ETOPO1 Global relief model but couldn't find bathymetry information. SAFARI 2000 which you provided has some hydrographic data for the whole South Africa will take a look and see if they have any depth values. Thank you.

Comment: If none of these sources works out please let me know and I'll add a note in bold at the top of my answer. That way anyone else who tries to find an answer knows what we've already ruled out, so they don't waste time looking through the same sources.

Comment: your very first link was promising it River Discharge Data but doesn't have bathymetry data.